# How to fix encoding issue in sublime text

Tags: c++, sublimetext

I'm trying to fix an encoding issue I'm confronted with when using Sublime Text.

If I try to open a c++ file in sublime it displays the file's content as a series of hexadecimal numbers. I've tried to fix this by reopening it with all the various given encoding options ("File --> Reopen with Encoding"). I have also tried the following: "enable_hexadecimal_encoding": false under settings.

Is there something else I can do to fix this problem?

Screenshot when initially opened
[image]

Screenshot after reopening with UTF-8 encoding
[image]

Comment: It looks like you're trying to open a compiled binary file, not source code.

Comment: The `ELF` on line one gives away that this file is a compiled binary and not a source file. `cc` is an extension sometimes used for C++ files instead of `cpp`, which would lead me to guess that your compile command was something like `g++ WeekOneCourse.cc -o WeekOneCourse.cc`; that is, you clobbered over the input file with the compiled output. In any case, what you're seeing is, as pointed out, not an encoding error; you're trying to open the binary. Drop to the terminal and do `file WeekOneCourse.cc` in that folder to have the `file` utility tell you what kind of file you're trying to open.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have opened an object file(`.o`) with the wrong extension, I have checked it on my machine your file is originally an object file with possibly wrong extension. Read more about object files [here](https://qr.ae/TWphW0).

Try to find the original source file, a c++ source file will have an extension of `.cpp`(most likely).